# Strongly typed .NET Objects based on xsd vs LinqToXML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Could someone please help me with any good tools that I can use to generate .NET classes based on XSD?

The other option I've is to generate XML Document using Linq to XML. But this requires a hand coding of XML Elements and Attributes which is not very nice.

Regards

Comment: Does xsd.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx not work for you?

Comment: Yes it does. LINQTOXML vs XSD.EXE, which one is better?

Comment: I have checked Xsd2Code . It is a way better than xsd.exe with lots of options. I think both options is more time saving than LINQ to XML, how ever with LINQ to XML you have all the power

Comment: Thanks @caglar_gonul appreciate your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/), It's like xsd.exe on steroids - and without the bugs..

Comment: Thanks @MattDavey is xsd2Code better than LinqToXml. On what scenario we choose one then other?

Comment: @flybyte You gave the answer to that in your own question :) *using Linq to XML [...] this requires a hand coding of XML Elements and Attributes which is not very nice.*. Using Xsd2Code gives you strong typed objects - Xml elements become classes, Xml attributes become properties. This is a much more natural way to work in C#...

Answer (score 0):

Xsd.exe can be the tool that you are looking for : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's also [OpenLinqToXsd](http://openlinqtoxsd.codeplex.com/) for generating classes, tho that project hasn't been touched in about a year.  I've found that the obnoxious thing for xsd.exe is that you have to go through two lists to add 1 element type.

For ex.

```
<note>
    <pitch>
        <step>A</step>
        <alter>0</alter>
        <octave>4</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>4</duration>
<note>
```

I had to add crap into two separate lists, one that had the actual data and one that just described the field I was putting in.  For LinqToXsd, I would just do:

```
var n = new note() {
 pitch = new List<pitch>() {
  new pitch() {
   step = A, alter = 0, octave = 4
 } }, duration = new List<decimal>() { 4 } 
};
```

Bad news is that everything is done with `IList<T>` which doesn't support EditItem (for WPF purposes, yuck).  Good luck on finding something free, fresh & recent, and works with everything.  I've been mucking with this stuff for 6 months now and beyond frustrated.